# find a jacobian for an ODE on Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

i have a system of ode y1'=4*y2+y1;y2'=y2*y1+y1-y2. and i know how to get the critical point but i do not know how to get the jacobian in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your odes' which are

```
ClearAll[y1, y2, t]
ode1 = y1'[t] == 4*y2[t] + y1[t]
ode2 = y2'[t] == y2[t]*y1[t] + y1[t] - y2[t]
```

Then we see that

```
f1 = 4*y2+y1;
f2 = y2*y1+y1-y2
```

Then the Jacobian matrix is

```
(j=Grad[{f1,f2},{y1,y2}])//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Your system:

```
f1[y1_[t_],y2_[t_]]=4*y2[t]+y1[t];
f2[y1_[t_],y2_[t_]]=y2[t]*y1[t]+y1[t]-y2[t];
F[{y1_[t_],y2_[t_]}]:=Evaluate[{f1[y1[t],y2[t]],f2[y1[t],y2[t]]}];
X={y1[t],y2[t]};
```

Equilibrium points:

```
eqp=Solve[F[X]==0,X];
X1=eqp[[1]];
X2=eqp[[2]];
MatrixForm@ReplaceAll[X1][F[X]]
MatrixForm@ReplaceAll[X2][F[X]]
```

The Jacobian matrix:

```
J[{y1_[t_],y2_[t_]}]:=Evaluate@D[F[X],{X}];
MatrixForm@J[X]
```

$$\text{J}(X)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 \text{y}_{2}(t)+1 & \text{y}_{1}(t)-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Linear approximations:

```
MatrixForm@ReplaceAll[X1][J[X]]
MatrixForm@ReplaceAll[X2][J[X]]
```